# How to change projection of map in geonode 3.0?

Tags: openlayers, geospatial, openstreetmap, geoserver

I'm new to geonode, I just installed version 3 and looking to add some layers which are in EPSG:2039 , I'm able to see the layers in geoserver and postgres, but not on map in geonode.
I thought I needed to change coordinate system of map. But when I did some research and looked for folder inside static/geonode/js I can't fine ms2 folder.[image]

but ironically, I can see the folder and files in inspect tab of my app.
Any help,
Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve it 